# .on event not working on new added button jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

**I have a div that contain sample table with one TR**

```
<div>
<table id="sample_row" style="width:300px">
<tr>
<td>
<select id="employer">
  <option value="1">Employer 1</option>
  <option value="2">Employer 2</option>
  <option value="3">Employer 3</option>
  <option value="4">Employer 4</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select id="location">
  <option value="1">Location 1</option>
  <option value="2">Location 2</option>
  <option value="3">Location 3</option>
  <option value="4">Location 4</option>
</select>
 </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="subArea"></td>
  <td>
<select id="employeeType">
  <option value="1">Part Time</option>
  <option value="2">Leased</option>
  <option value="3">Temporary</option>
  <option value="4">Full Time</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type="button" value="Save" id="save" class="save"></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Cancle" id="cancle"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**The following is my jQuery function**

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#save").on("click", function(){
     alert("##");
});
    $("#add").click(function(){
    var tr =$("#sample_row tr:first").clone();
    $('#services_list tbody').prepend('<tr />').children('tr:first').replaceWith(tr);

});

});
</script>
```

Row Added successfully, **but `.on` event not working on new added button with tr?**

Comment: What exactly is not working..? what ae you trying to do..? where's `#services_list` ? Where's `#add`?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @Pbk1303 jquery-1.11.1.min

Comment: @TilwinJoy I not mentioned #services_list

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor It's right there in your code.

Comment: @TilwinJoy ok! but `$("body").on("click", "#save", function(){
     alert("##");
});` worked for me :)

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor that's great for you. but this question does not fit the rules of StackOverflow. `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.` next time include all the details to reproduce the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

```
$("body").on("click", ".save", function(){
     alert("##");
});
```

You can even replace `body` by `#sample_row`  :)

Comment: First of of, the cloning part of his code won't work. hence this solution is useless.

Comment: -1 simply because of the duplicated `id`'s that will be bound to. You should bind to the `.save` selector as `id`'s should be unique to ***one*** and only ***one*** element. I'll remove my downvote if the improper use of `id`'s is corrected.

Comment: @ Tilwin Joy  pardon me I am unable to get what do you want to convey?

Comment: Yup completely agree with War10ck, there should only and only one id, updated the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The power of `on` event is second parameter, otherwise it is same as click handler.

```
$(document).on("click", ".save", function(){
     alert("##");
});
```

Above code will check for click event inside document and if target element is `#save` it will call event.

Always use class when you think of multiple items, dont use ID in that case.

Comment: Perhaps you would expand this to cover "why" this answer should address his issue...

Comment: `id`'s should be unique. This would be fine for one row but if it's multiple, you'll want to use the `.save` class selector instead.

Comment: I know you can use the same ID throughout your document. It's wrong though. You shouldn't. ID's should be unique to ***one*** element.

Comment: @War10ck Yes you are correct. that is how it should be but i just want to say it will work in jquery on event. however let me change it to class

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you need to delegate to a parent in the DOM for future added elements. Also the fact that you should not be duplicating ids, should be corrected.

The .on function can delegate to parent elements so that future added elements can be bound.  The second parameter in the on() statement below allows me to bind the click event to the #samle_row and delegate for the targeted element ".save"

```
$("#sample_row").on("click",".save",function(){
     alert("##");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('body')
    .on('click', '.save', function (event) {
        alert("##");
    })
    .on('click', '#add', function (event) {
       var tr =$("#sample_row tr:first").clone();
        $('#services_list tbody').prepend('<tr />').children('tr:first').replaceWith(tr);
    }
);
```

Comment: Cloning part was describes as 'working' by author. Therefore it was copied.